# How do I create a New Public GitHub Repository and push my locally stored, newly created code to my GitHub account?

Tags: github

I have a folder on my hard drive. It contains files that I would like to have in a New, Public GitHub Repository. What sequence of terminal commands would I use to accomplish this?

Googled it. Tried the provided instructions to add locally hosted code to GitHub provided here: https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github

Comment: There are instructions on the black repo page (I don't remember them)

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is very good at guiding you through this.

This is done in two stages. First, you create a new Github repo. Then you add your existing files to that repo.

- Create a new GitHub repo by visiting [https://github.com/[username]?tab=repositories](https://github.com/%5Busername%5D?tab=repositories) and pressing the green "New" button in the top right corner.
- Fill in the details of your new repo and press the green "Create repository" button in the bottom right corner.

When you create a new repo, GitHub presents you with a list of instructions on how to get files into that repo in a number of different ways. The section you want is called **…or push an existing repository from the command line**

But first we need to ensure we have a local `git` repo. You say you have a directory of files, but it sounds like they aren't in a `git` repo. So follow these instructions (if you do already have a local `git`, then you can ignore these lines):

- Open a command line window and go to the directory containing your files.
- Initialise an empty local `git` repo - `git init`
- Add your files to the local `git repo` - `git add .`
- Commit your files - `git commit -m 'Initial commit`

Now you have an empty GitHub repo and a local `git` repo with your files in it. The next (and final step) is to link the two together by following the instructions on the GitHub repo's web page. They will be something like this:

- `git remote add origin git@github.com:[username]/[reponame].git`
- `git branch -M main`
- `git push -u origin main`

If you now refresh the web page for your GitHub repo, you'll see the setup instructions have been replaced with your files.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:-

1. Github account. [Github](https://github.com)
2. Git installed and configured on the system(recommended). [Download git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Follow the steps below:

1. Open the command line and navigate to the folder you want to upload to Git Hub.
2. Initialize git inside the folder, with the command: `git init`
3. Add the files to the staging area with the command: `git add .`
4. Now, commit the files with the command: `git commit -m "your message"`
5. Now go to [Github new repo](https://github.com/new), and enter the name of your repository, make sure you don't check the *add README.md* option, see this [image].
6. Click on **Create repository**.
7. Now a new page as below will open [image: github new repo]
8. Now copy the code to push an existing repository, and paste them in your local terminal.
9. Press enter and done(note: you have to authenticate your terminal the first time with Git Hub).
10. Your code is pushed.